# flutter loop through firebase node that consists of singlenodes and nodes with children

Tags: json, firebase, dart, flutter

I have this piece of code:

```
  routineExersiceIDsetter() async{
    String routineId;
     final response = await reference.child(_userId).once();
     response.value.forEach((k,v){
       if(v["name"] == "First Routine"){
         currentRoutineId = k;
         routineId = k;
       }
     });
     final response2 = await reference.child(_userId).child(currentRoutineId).once();
     response2.value.forEach((k, v){
         if(v["name"] == "Day 1"){
           currentSchemeId = k;
       }

     });
  }
```

and this piece of a firebase database

```
{
  "-LBNflaqFEb4DtZiYxnh" : {
    "-LBWa99g4yCstUBkDGa7" : {
      "name" : "Day 1"
    },
    "name" : "First Routine"
  }
}
```

the first forEach line works but the second doesn't. Is there a way to make this work or do I need to change my firebase architecture?

Comment: Don't you have to chain the two requests? Queries to Firebase are asynchronous so you should wait the first query resolves to have the value of currentRoutineId and only then you can execute the second query. I don't know how to chain that in dart, so I cannot help you with a full solution.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I thought I already did that with the await request the perror i get is : type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Comment: I don't know dart but I have the feeling you are not linking the two `await`s. Are you sure `currentRoutineId` has a correct value in the second 'await'? Can you check with console or log?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec from what I've seen it gets the correct routineid but it still gives an error in the second foreach

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Because it seems all the info is under one node

Comment: I want to find the key that belongs to the name Day 1

Comment: What do you exactly get with response.value. Can you output this object to the console?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec for response2.value i get this: {name: First Routine, -LBWa99g4yCstUBkDGa7: {name: Day 1}} and response.value i get {-LBNflaqFEb4DtZiYxnh: {name: First Routine, -LBWa99g4yCstUBkDGa7: {name: Day 1}}}

Comment: Thanks for the help @RenaudTarnec I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I realised is should have wrapped the second ifstatement in another ifstatement:

```
if(k!="name"){
   if(v["name"] == "Day 1"){
     currentSchemeId =k;
   }
}
```